# In 2 GB RAM installed computer, in task manager performance tab (Available + cached + Free ) memory add up only to about 1.2GB?

Tags: windows-7, memory

I have installed windows 7 in one of my machine. It has 2 GB RAM but when work for some time it gets very slow when see performance tab of windows task manager (Available + cached + Free ) memory not add up to 2 GB its some what very less than that( last check 1.2 GB).?

Cached memory showed after some time >500 MB. Please explain exactly how to control cached memory that shows up in task manager performance tab. computer becomes very slow  after some time when this value goes high.?

Comment: The memory columns in Task Manager do not accurately represent the memory usage of a Windows machine. I would recommend something like Process Explorer from SysInternals instead.

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: Yeah - you cannot add up memory like that - it's not so simple. Refer to [this related q](http://superuser.com/q/153574/4377)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click `Start`, type in `Resource Monitor` and press Enter. Now click on the `Memory` tab for a better representation of your RAM usage (including total memory).

Sample screenshot from Google Images:
[image: Sample screenshot from Google Images]