# Decreasing cached memory and increasing Free memory in RAM

Tags: 64-bit, memory, windows-server-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows 7 memory usage](https://superuser.com/questions/153574/windows-7-memory-usage)

[image]

Hi,

I'm using windows 2008 server 64 bit OS, I've uploaded the snap shot of my task manager when minimum processes running

It shows Total memory 8190 MB *Cached memory 4315 MB* Free 3402 MB

So effectively I get only 3402 MB of total RAM usage My question here is more than half is used for cached memory is there any means I can decrease this cached memory, in turn I can increase my free memory. I need to do this because my Application requires at least 5GB RAM and it crashed when run in this system. Please give me a solution for this

Thanks in advance

Comment: Crossposting does not impress.

Comment: Not to nitpick or anything, but I don't remember there being a windows 2007 server... Anyways, have you tried upping the Virtual Memory?

Answer (score 4):

Windows does this automatically.  As soon as programs request more memory, the MM module reclaims the cached memory.

Edit: I was wrong.  They actually implemented this back in **Vista**.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2007.03.vistakernel.aspx

Comment: Is this feature available in other windows?

Comment: When my application crashed Cached memory was around 4 GB and free memory was ZERO

Comment: @Athreya Free memory being at (or near) zero is good, it means that it is actually being used for *something* and likely has nothing to do with your application crashing.  As surfasb stated "cached" memory is released as and when the system needs it as it is simply caching data that is read from the disk.  Think of "cached" as "being used but actually available for programs" memory.

Comment: Crashing an application has really nothing to do with free memory. Depending on the application and how it is written, applications can get unstable at even 1.5GB.  This is due to the atrociously resource intensive nature of pulling data out of memory as compared to just fetching things out of cache. Another thing is the application could of crashed due to other reasons. Just because it asks the operating system for that much memory, doesn't mean it is using it all (ask the C++ guys.  This is what they constantly bash on new programmers about).

Comment: More than likely, a program is consuming that much memory because of an internal error and parts of it are terminating early without releasing it's resources.